# How to stop react/electron from rewriting GET requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am using react along with electron to create a native app and I would like to pass a file path from my main electron process to one of my react components to render the HTML in the file. I decided to do this using the URL, so I route using this:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/3D-Graph/*" element={
              <UserContext.Provider value={"3D-Graph"}>
                <GraphApp />
              </UserContext.Provider>
            } />

            <Route path="/" element={
              <UserContext.Provider value={"2D-Graph"}>
                <GraphApp />
              </UserContext.Provider>
            } />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
  );
}
```

And then I grab the HTML using this in my GraphApp component:

```js
const htmlFile = new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search).get('graph-path')
```

However, when I run this, I get this output: `Rewriting GET /index.html/3D-Graph/?graph-path=3D-Graph to /index.html`

I don't know if this is being done by electron when I use the loadURL function or if react does this during its routing. How would I stop it from doing this so I can route the app? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Ive sent file paths from main in the past like this:

Main:

```
win.webContents.send(”file-path-reply”, ”PATH TO YOUR FILE”)
```

Or:

```
ipcMain.on("eventFromRenderer", (event) => {
   event.sender.send(”file-path-reply”, ”PATH TO YOUR FILE”)
 }
```

Render:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
const [htmlPath, setHtmlPath] = useState(””);

useEffect(() => {
 const reply = (evt, message) => {      
 setHtmlPath(message);
}

ipcRenderer.on(”file-path-reply”, reply);

}, []);
// use htmlPath…
}
```

Hope this helps! Caseing is a bit weird, ive written this with autocorrect on my phone :)